# Updates In before Trigger

Tags: apex

I am curious what the rules are for using an update statement in a before insert trigger.

The below code is called during a before insert trigger on tasks. Basically what I am doing is saying "Hey, there is a new task associated with this opportunity. Let's check to see if there are any other open tasks associated with this opp. If there are, let's close them up"

```
public with sharing class NextStepDueDateTask 
{

    public static void handleTrigger(List<Task> newTasks) {

        Set<Id> OppIds = new Set<Id>();

        for(Task t: newTasks)
        {   
            // Grab all tasks that are related to Opportunities and are Open
            String s1 = t.WhatId != null ? String.valueof(t.WhatId) : '';  
            if(s1.startsWith('006') && t.status == 'Open')
            {
                OppIds.add(oppId);
            }
        }

        List<Opportunity> Opps = [ SELECT id, (SELECT id, status from Tasks WHERE status = 'open' ) from Opportunity where id in :OppIds ];

        set<Task> tasksToUpdate = new List<Task>();

        for(Opportunity opp : Opps)
        {
            if(opp.Tasks != null)
            {
                for( Task t : opp.Tasks  )
                {
                    t.Status = 'Completed';
                    tasksToUpdate.add(t);
                }
            }
        }

        update tasksToUpdate;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Cross object logic definitively belongs in the after context. See **[Triggers](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_triggers.htm)**:

> There are two types of triggers:
>
> - *Before triggers* are used to update or validate record values before they’re saved to the database.
> - *After triggers* are used to access field values that are set by the system (such as a record's Id or LastModifiedDate field), and to affect changes in other records, such as logging into an audit table or firing asynchronous events with a queue. The records that fire the *after trigger* are read-only.

Again,

> ***After triggers* are used ... to affect changes in other records**

If you are aiming to update sibling records, do so in an `after` trigger. If you want to just update records which look up to an `Opportunity`, that does belong in the `before` context, but should not invoke any DML Statements, and actually does not even require queries.

```
for (Task record : newTasks)
{
    if (record.WhatId != null && record.WhatId.getSObjectType() == Opportunity.sObjectType)
    {
        record.Status = 'Completed';
    }
}
```

Comment: nit: `record.WhatId.getSObjectType` sb `record.WhatId.getSObjectType()`

Comment: @crop and the double `==` oops!